# python multiprocessing shared dict of queues

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a parallel priority queue in Python multiprocessing. The data structure I'm using is an Sorted Dict of Queues. So to get the first element I just get the highest priority key and return the Queue associated with it.

I'm having trouble fitting this into the multiprocessing framework. I've gotten a shared sorted dictionary object by extending the sortedcontainers SortedDict class using BaseProxy and BaseManager. However, I'm unsure of how to set the multiprocessing.Queue objects inside the sorted dictionary

Here's what I have so far:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, BaseProxy
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class PriorityQueueClass(SortedDict):
    pass

class PriorityQueueProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__len__', '__setitem__', '__getitem__', 'peekitem')
    def __len__(self):
        return self._callmethod('__len__')

    def __getitem__(self, tuple):
        return self._callmethod('__getitem__', tuple)

    def __setitem__(self, tuple):
        key, item = tuple
        queue = Queue()
        queue.put(item)
        return self._callmethod('__setitem__', (key, queue))

    def peekitem(self, tuple=(0,)):
        return self._callmethod('peekitem', tuple)



class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('PriorityQueue', PriorityQueueClass, PriorityQueueProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    pq = manager.PriorityQueue()
    pq.__setitem__((1, 2))
    pq.__setitem__((0, 2))
    pq.__getitem__(0)
```

which raises the exception:

```
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

Fairly certain this is because I'm trying to initialize a manager in my `__setitem__` to initialize the process-safe queue. Unclear of how else to do this/if it is possible

Comment: Have you figured out a solution for this?